# How to restrict task assignment to only juniors

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, task-list, task-assignment

I have a situation that some time a junior employee is assigning task to his manager or other senior employee of the organization.

I want to restrict it ,to that any employee will only be able to assign task to it junior level employees !!

Comment: Are you sure that will be a good idea? I can a lot of scenarios where that will cause more problems than it will solve. That aside it will require that your AD manager field is updated for everybody all the time

Comment: Ad fields are no worry for me,  by the way what kind of problems you are indicating !

Comment: A group of peers are having a meeting, who can assign task?

Comment: A team where the members are from different part of the org.

Comment: A managers PA can't assign any tasks, the manager will have to do it herself

Answer (score 0):

As first it sounds like a good idea, but it greatly reduces the flexibility, and causes people to bypass this restriction by using Outlook. So the short answer is, don't